# jQuery UI Accordion: start page without a selected section

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an Accordion style of navigation section on a website at work and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to set it up so that there isn't a selected section when the page loads...basically you see all the headings but none of the content.

Also not sure that it's relevant, but the site is built on MVC3 using C#

Code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#accordion').accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Employee Stock Ownership Plan Announcement</a></h3>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_Esop")
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">TAG Transport Purchase</a></h3>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_TagPurchase")
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">Wilcox Truck Line Purchase</a></h3>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_WilcoxPurchase")
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">JRI, Inc. Mentorship</a></h3>
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_JRIMentor")
    </div>
</div>
```

Corrected code based on selected answer...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#accordion').accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            fillSpace: true,
            clearStyle: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

This did two things.

1. Made it so that when the page loaded there was no active content.
2. Removed the scroll bar from the panels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(".selector").accordion({ active: false });
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great.  A 'bug' that popped up with this now is that some of the windows have scroll bars when they didn't before.  Any thoughts on this?  The scroll bars aren't the end of the world, but I'd prefer not to have them.

Comment: The issue you describe in your comments can result from different things. This page provides a number of solutions: http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/javascript/how-to-avoid-scrollbars-when-using-jquery-accordion

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active : 'none' });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKsTz/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `collapsible` option to `true` is part of the solution, you also need to set the `active` option to `false`